# How to break a loop which is inside the Thread, using a button on Android

Tags: android, loops, methods, for-loop, try-catch

I wanted to break the loop which is inside the Thread timer by use stop button. But Ecclips shows error "*Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)*" on stopsound(); method inside the Thread timer.

I know that we cant defining a function inside a for loop, that why am getting the error. But i just wanted to know, how can we break the loop which is inside the Thread timer by using stop button ?

```
stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
public void onClick(View v) {
        stopsound();
           }
    });

public void mpsleep() {
    mp.start();
    Thread timer= new Thread(){//create new  thread with anonymous class
        public void run(){
            try{
                for (i= 0;i< maxCount;i++){
                    sleep(5000);//5 pause
                    public void stopsound(){
                            break;
                        }
                }               
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();//print the stack trace if have an error
            }finally{
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mp.pause();
                        mp.seekTo(0);
                        loop=0;
                        bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.playzz);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

Found other way to break it, but it breaks only after 5 seconds after the stop button is pressed.

```
int loop=0;
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
public void onClick(View v) {
    loop=1
       }
});
public void mpsleep() {
Thread timer= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                for (i= 0;i< maxCount;i++){
                    sleep(5000);//5 pause
                    if (loop==1){
                        break;
                    }
                }               
            }finally{
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mp.pause();
                        mp.seekTo(0);
                        loop=0;
                        bv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    }
                });
            }}
```

How can we break the for-loop instantly after stopbutton is clicked ??

Comment: You are defining a function inside a for loop ?

Comment: I know we cant defining a function inside a for loop. But i just wanted to know how to achieve this.

Comment: @SaiKiran, My advice to you is to get a bit more practice with Java before trying to tackle Android.

Comment: @SaiKiran I'm trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish with the code you have presented us. Can you explain what you are trying to do with this code? What is its purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you wrote is not valid Java syntax. You can't declare a method inside of another method declaration.

If you want to write looping code that you can break out of, you can declare a `volatile` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) boolean variable outside of the Thread, and check its value inside of the thread. Your thread would just loop over the variable checking its value, then break when it changes.

That said, it looks like you are trying to write code that uses the `MediaPlayer` to play music. You should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for this, not a Thread.

See the developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices